# Split a string to work on different parts and combine back into one var again

Tags: sas

I'm working on a code to split a string basis a keyword and translate the before and after values of that string in the variable. Below is the code that I've written:

```
data have;
infile cards dsd;
length name $50.;
input name $ ACCOUNT_ID $ cust_id;

cards;
ARTHUR CORP LTD.,CC1234,1234
TOM ABN LIST,eil1235,1235
MIKEZ,tb1236,1236
MATT,mb1237,1237
LIZ ABN TB1238,1238
PIZ,VB1239,1239
TAN TRUST,MB1240,1240
PANDA,,1241
;
run;

%MACRO MSK (IN_DS=,VAR=,OUT_DS=);

DATA &OUT_DS;
SET &IN_DS;


RETAIN CIPHER _CHAR_ ;
RETAIN COUNT;
LENGTH ORIGINAL $26;


ORIGINAL = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";


IF _N_ = 1 THEN DO;
CIPHER = COMPRESS(SUBSTR(ORIGINAL,5) 
%DO I = 1 %TO 4;
||SUBSTR(ORIGINAL,&I,1)
%END;
);
&VAR = TRANSLATE(UPCASE(&VAR),ORIGINAL,CIPHER);
COUNT = 1;
END;


ELSE DO;
&VAR = TRANSLATE(UPCASE(&VAR),ORIGINAL,CIPHER);
COUNT = COUNT + 1;
END;
DROP COUNT CIPHER ORIGINAL;


RUN;

%MEND;
%MSK(IN_DS=HAVE,VAR=NAME,OUT_DS=OUT);
```

I now need to TRANSLATE the name column: everything apart from the keywords CORP and ABN, so translate everything before and after CORP/ABN in the columnn.
Also, I need to pass the keywords CORP and ABN as values in a parameter.
Can someone suggest how I can achieve that please.

The expected output for the NAME column is :

```
WNPDQN CORP HPZ.
PKI ABN HEOP
IEGAV
IWPP
HEV ABN PX1238
PWJ PNQOP
LWJZW
```

Comment: Was the original purpose to remove the ABN and CORP portions or does it go beyond that? Can you show us what you want as output for that sample data? This is a well asked question as well :)

Comment: The original purpose was to remove everything, which is why i created the code above, now I need to translate everything apart from CORP and ABN.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my comment. If you can answer the other questions I think it can be solved. I don't know that I have time today, but I'm sure someone else will especially if you add the piece about expected output.

Comment: Sure Reeza : The intended output for the Name Column is :                 `WNPDQN CORP HPZ.
PKI ABN HEOP
IEGAV
IWPP
HEV ABN PX1238
PWJ PNQOP
LWJZW`

Comment: can you please show your final output dataset should like in main window not in comments

Comment: I've updated the original question with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

`TRANSLATE` can be considered a simple character substitution cipher if the ***to*** parameters are unique characters.  If the ***to*** parameters are not unique you will have the situation of more than one source letter mapping to the same translated letter.

Based on the expected outcome, the substitution cipher for this question is

```
A -> W
B -> X
C -> Y
D -> Z
E -> A
F -> B
G -> C
H -> D
I -> E
J -> F
K -> G
L -> H
M -> I
N -> J
O -> K
P -> L
Q -> M
R -> N
S -> O
T -> P
U -> Q
V -> R
W -> S
X -> T
Y -> U
Z -> V
```

The non-ciphering of `CORP` and `ABM` could cause a deciphering problem when the original input has terms `GSVL` -> `CORP` or `EFR` -> `ABN`

Because you are ciphering only parts of the variable, you will have to

- scan the value into parts and cipher only the non-CORP non-ABN parts
- reassemble the parts

`SCAN` returns only the part and not the position, so will have to also `INDEXW` to determine where the scanned part came from in the value.

A simpler approach might be to cipher the entire value and decipher only the CORP and ABN words, for example:

```
data have;
infile cards dsd dlm=',';
length name $50. account_id $32 cust_id 8;
input name ACCOUNT_ID cust_id;
cards;
ARTHUR CORP LTD.,CC1234,1234
TOM ABN LIST,eil1235,1235
MIKEZ,tb1236,1236
MATT,mb1237,1237
LIZ ABN,TB1238,1238
PIZ,VB1239,1239
TAN TRUST,MB1240,1240
PANDA,,1241
;
run;

data want;
  set have;

  retain cipherbet 'WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV';
  retain alphabet  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  name_ciphered = translate(name,cipherbet,alphabet);

  * undo ciphering;
  pos = 1;
  do while (1);
     pos = findw(name,'CORP',' ','O',pos); if pos = 0 then leave;
     substr(name_ciphered,pos,4) = 'CORP'; pos+5;
  end;
  pos = 1;
  do while (1);
     pos = findw(name,'ABN',' ','O',pos); if pos = 0 then leave;
     substr(name_ciphered,pos,3) = 'ABN'; pos + 4;
  end;

  name = name_ciphered;

  drop cipherbet alphabet pos name_ciphered;
run;
```

`SUBSTR` on the left hand side of `=` does an in-value replacement and can be effective for this problem.

Different cipherbets based on alphabet rotation starting point can be set up with

```
%let start = 23;
%let alphabet = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ;
%let cipherbet = %substr(%substr(&alphabet,&start)&alphabet,1,26);

%put &alphabet;
%put &cipherbet;

data want;
  set have;

  name_ciphered = translate(name,"&cipherbet","&alphabet");

  * undo ciphering;
  pos = 1;
  do while (1);
     pos = findw(name,'CORP',' ','O',pos); if pos = 0 then leave;
     substr(name_ciphered,pos,4) = 'CORP'; pos+5;
  end;
  pos = 1;
  do while (1);
     pos = findw(name,'ABN',' ','O',pos); if pos = 0 then leave;
     substr(name_ciphered,pos,3) = 'ABN'; pos + 4;
  end;

  name = name_ciphered;

  drop pos name_ciphered;
run;
```